# view de problemas no eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Olá.

Quando copilo um programa e vou na view de problemas, o eclipse mostra problemas e alertas de outros projetos já copilados antes. Como posso fazer para não fechar o eclipse e apenas focar no projeto que estou trabalhando? A mesma situação acontece quando o programa entra em loop infinito. Não consigo parar a view de console. Ou seja, como posso corrigir esta questão de views?

Comment: Acho que é só fechar os outros projetos, clicando com o botão direito neles e depois em "Fechar" no popup menu que abrir nele. Já fez isso?

Comment: Sobre o loop infinito, tem um botão de stop na aba console do eclipse.

Comment: @Math♦ geralmente não fecho os projetos. Me faltou experimentar isso.

Comment: Esses alertas não chegam a encomodar ou tirar o foco, quando usava a IDE, nunca tive esse problema. Outra dica é, ao invés de fechar os projetos, crie grupos de projetos, assim você separa os já concluídos dos que você está desenvolvendo, ou como quiser guarda-los.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe criar working sets é legal para organizar os projetos, entretanto isso não faz os warnings desaparecerem

Comment: @Math realmente, fiz o teste e não some mesmo hehe. Me confundi com o netbeans, pois nele cada grupo de projeto é independente. Creio que a melhor solução seja fechar os projetos mesmo, ou criar outra workspace.

Comment: é, não sei se separando criteriosamente resolviria

Answer (score 0):

Para o eclipse focar apenas nas views dum projeto, selecione os outros projetos, no menu project clique em fechar. Você não acessará as views de outros projetos, facilitando a visualização de problemas e alertas do seu projeto de trabalho.